# postgresql show month start date and end date based on given dates

Tags: sql, postgresql

I need to pull out first date and last date of the month from the given from_date and to_date as input, For Example:-

I have my psql output table as the following:

| Year | Term | Start Date | End Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022 | Odd | 01-02-2022 | 30-04-2022 |
| 2022 | Even | 01-07-2022 | 30-09-2022 |

I need the output as the following:-

| Year | Term | Start Date | End Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022 | Odd | 01-02-2022 | 28-02-2022 |
| 2022 | Odd | 01-03-2022 | 31-03-2022 |
| 2022 | Odd | 01-04-2022 | 30-04-2022 |
| 2022 | Even | 01-07-2022 | 30-07-2022 |
| 2022 | Even | 01-08-2022 | 31-08-2022 |
| 2022 | Even | 01-09-2022 | 30-09-2022 |

I need the ouput in Postgresql, Pls help
Thanks

Comment: And what is the definition of the task actually? To produce 2 groups of months - those whose number is even and those whose number is odd? You don't need a database for that - January is odd, February is even, and so on ...

Comment: hi @IVOGELOV, no actually the task is to produce the first and last date of each month from a give input like from date and to date, say for example 01-Jan-2022 to 30-Apr-2022, is the from date and to date, i need output like 01-feb-2022 as start date, 28-feb-2022 end date till april ? did u understand

Comment: Welcome to the SO community. The community will help you with your issues, however there are some expectations form you. Please spend a few minutes to take the [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and review [ask]. In particular here post your table definition (ddl script), sample input as text - **no images**, of better a [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14). Also post and what you have tried and the expected output of that sample data

Comment: Hi @Belayer I'll post you the postgresql query below. 
select
 ay.name as academic_year,
 ayt.start_date as start_date,
  ayt.end_date as end_date
 
 
from academic_year_term as ayt
join academic_year as ay on ay.id = ayt.academic_year_id
where ayt.active = True

Comment: Hi @Belayer Actually I need the output as the month start date and month end date based on the given input (start date and end date). I have posted the output image on the top

Answer (score 1):

Your issue boils down to *given a period with start and end dates, determine the first and last dates for each month in that period*. In Postgres given a date you can determine the first (with [date_trunc](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-TRUNC) function) and last of the a month with the expressions:

```
-- for a given date
date_trunc('month', given_date)   -- returns first day of month  
date_trunc('month', given_date + interval '1 month' - interval '1 day') -- returns last day of month
```

Use the first expression above, with [generate_series](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/functions-srf.html) with dates, to create the first of each month in the period. The use the second expression to generate the end of each month. (see [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=f5514286f84f1d672caded8405bd6956))

```
with range_dates (year, term, gsom) as 
     ( select year 
           , term 
           , generate_series(  date_trunc('month', od.start_date)::date
                            ,  date_trunc('month', od.end_date )::date
                            ,  interval '1 month'
                            )::date      
      from output_data od                   
     ) 
select year 
     , term 
     , gsom   start_date
     , (gsom + interval '1 month' - interval '1 day')::date end_date
  from range_dates
 order by term desc, start_date;
```